# Kill selected file(s) in Recycle Bin

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a purging tool that lists and destroys (using Kill) any files in certain locations on a user's PC. My tool works well in all locations except for Recycle Bin (C:\$Recycle.Bin).

I am getting the following error:

> Run-time error '75': Path/File access error

How can I manage to circumvent this error to delete/kill the file in Recycle Bin? I don't want to empty the whole Recycle Bin. I want to remove selected files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to access the real Recycle-Bin folder. This is a system folder which can be accessed via `NameSpace`-method of an `Shell.Application`-Object. You need to pass a number to this method (I found a list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants?redirectedfrom=MSDN)), for the Recycle Bin it is `&HA&` (called *BitBucket*)

When you have the folder, you can loop over the items in it, just note that it may contain files and folders and you have to distinguish. You can use a `FileSystemObject` to remove the files/folders you want.

```
Sub RemoveFromRecyleBin()

    Const BITBUCKET = &HA&

    Dim sh As Object, folder as Object, fso As Object
    Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set folder = sh.Namespace(BITBUCKET)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim item As Object
    For Each item In folder.Items
        Debug.Print item.Type, item.Name, item.Path

        If InStr(item.Name, "Junk") Then  ' Replace by your own logic
            If item.IsFolder Then
                fso.DeleteFolder item.Path
            Else
                fso.DeleteFile item.Path
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Beautiful! :) Few things **1.** Worth a mention that reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library is necessary **2.** The code works for all files expcept zip files. Somehow it thinks it is a folder `item.IsFolder` and not a file. If you step through the code and then execute `fso.DeleteFile item.Path` then it will work. Maybe check for the extention and then use  `.DeleteFile`? **3.** Change `InStr(item.Name, "Junk")` to `If InStr(1, item.Name, "Junk", vbTextCompare) Then` to avoid case sensitive search... Overall. A brillaint piece of code!

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Was not aware about the problem with the Zip, thanks for the hint. I changed the code so now no reference to the Scripting Lib is needed.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you so much.

I applied this as a Function passing the SearchTerm in via variable. 

Instead of Instr I used the following:
If LCase(item.Name) Like "*" & LCase(SearchTerm) & "*" Then

. I really appreciate your assistance, thank you!